# Replace alphabet in a string using replace?

Tags: java, replace

I'm wondering if I can use `string.replace()` to replace all alphabets in a string?

```
String sentence = "hello world! 722"
String str = sentence.replace("what to put here", "@");
//now str should be "@@@@@ @@@@@! 722"
```

In other words, how do I represent alphabetic characters?

Alternatives are welcomed too, unless too long.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Java's [`String#replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) takes a regex string as argument. Tha being said, `[a-ZA-Z]` matches any char from `a` to `z` (lowercase) and `A` to `Z` (uppercase) and that seems to be what you need.

```
String sentence = "hello world! 722";
String str = sentence.replaceAll("[a-zA-Z]", "@");
System.out.println(str); // "@@@@@ @@@@@! 722"
```

See [**demo** here](http://ideone.com/PUgewO).

Comment: More about the `[a-zA-Z]` regex here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html

Answer (score 6):

Use [`String#replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) that takes a **Regex**:

```
str = str.replaceAll("[a-zA-Z]", "@");
```

Note that [`String#replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) takes a String as argument and not a *Regex*. If you still want to use it, you should loop on the String char-by-char and check whether this char is in the range [a-z] or [A-Z] and *replace* it with `@`. But if it's not a homework and you can use `replaceAll`, use it :)

Comment: @Arch1tect That's not weird, my mistake :))

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following (regular expression):

```
    String test = "hello world! 722";
    System.out.println(test);
    String testNew = test.replaceAll("(\\p{Alpha})", "@");
    System.out.println(testNew);
```

You can read all about it in here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/index.html

Comment: I'd say this is more of a primary solution, with the a-zA-Z solutions being alternatives for pretty much English locales only.  (Hawaiian works, too. :^)

Answer (score 0):

You replace using regular expressions with [`String#replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-). The pattern `[a-zA-Z]` will match all lowercase English letters (`a-z`) and all uppercase ones (`A-Z`). See the below code in action [here](https://ideone.com/ZTqk91).

```
final String result = str.replaceAll("[a-zA-Z]","@");
```

If you want to replace all alphabetical characters from all locales, use the pattern `\p{L}`. The documentation for [`Pattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) states that:

> Both \p{L} and \p{IsL} denote the category of Unicode letters.

See the below code in action [here](https://ideone.com/YuSTM8).

```
final String result = str.replaceAll("\\p{L}", "@");
```