# Regex not removing A-Z and a-z

Tags: java, regex

```
String s = "xxx(000) 001";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("A-Za-z", ""));
```

Why is this printing `xxx(000) 001` instead of `(000) 001` removing all occurrences from `A-Z` and `a-z`?

Comment: Your answer is here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19886749/replace-alphabet-in-a-string-using-replace

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not using a correct regex you have to use a [Character classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) like this `[a-zA-Z]`:

```
s = s.replaceAll("[a-zA-Z]", "");
```

Comment: Thank you! Its fine now!

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the character class proposed by @YCF_L, I'd additionally use a quantifier:

```
s.replaceAll("[A-Za-z]+", "");
#                  ---^---
```

Otherwise, the internal replace function needs to be called multiple times.

---

For this example, consider the string `aa123bb` with the regular expression `[A-Za-z]`. The regex engine scans the string from left to right, and finds a match with `a` (it is in the character class). This match is reported back and replaced with `""` in our case. Then the next character is evaluated, which is another `a`: a match is reported and replaced. `1`, `2` and `3` are not included in our character class, but `b` and `b` indeed are. So in total with this expression the *internal* engine reports four matches back.

Now consider a quantifier like `[A-Za-z]+`: the engine finds `a` in `aa123bb` but is *greedy* and is eager to find another character which in our case is another `a`. It now reports a match with `aa` which is then replaced by `""`. `1`, `2` and `3` are not included in our character class so the engine leaves them as they are. Now, the engine finds `b` and (being greedy) yet another `b` (`bb` in total) and reports and replaces the second match.

While the result is the same (`123` in our case) the regex engine only needs to give back two results (and to call the replacement) with a quantifier instead of four without.

Comment: @Henry: Not really, no. The difference might be subtle but consider `aa123bb` - with the pattern by YCF_L you need 4 calls while with a quantifier only two to `replaceAll()`.

Comment: @Henry: Updated the answer (at the bottom) - a bit of a lengthy explanation, admittedly.

Comment: Explains much better what you mean. But probably it does not make much difference since the internal regex matcher is doing more work each time it is called. One would have to do some measurements to be sure.

Comment: @Henry: Well I am more the `Python` guy and have little to no experience with `Java`. However, timing both expressions on the string `aa123bb lorem ipsum lorem ipsum l=rem ips1m` with 100k iterations each yields **0.82** seconds for the accepted answer and **0.44** seconds for mine - roughly half the time.