# Is there a keyword that represent all the letters in the alphabet in Java

Tags: java

I know that there is a `String.replace()` method that can replace a letter with another character in a string. For example,

```
String str = “hellox”;
str.replace(‘x’,””)
```

Then `str` becomes `hello`.

My question is if there is a keyword that represent letters in the alphabet in general so that I can remove/replace all letters in the alphabet.
Example: `String str = “(have(hjdj)hjfb)”;`
I want `str = “(())”`

Comment: You need to use regular expression

Comment: What alphabet are you talking about? There is more than 1 ;-)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace alphabet in a string using replace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19886749/replace-alphabet-in-a-string-using-replace)

Comment: Why is this Question closed? It seems very much to be a programming question.

Comment: you would need `str = str.replace("x","");` (note the re-assignment to str) - replace doesn't change the string it is called on, but returns a new one

Answer (score 5):

You replace using regular expressions with [`String#replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-). The pattern `[a-zA-Z]` will match all lowercase English letters (`a-z`) and all uppercase ones (`A-Z`). See the below code in action [here](https://ideone.com/8WNvH3).

```
final String result = str.replaceAll("[a-zA-Z]","");
```

If you want to replace all alphabetical characters from all locales, use the pattern `\p{L}`. The documentation for [`Pattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) states that:

> Both \p{L} and \p{IsL} denote the category of Unicode letters.

See the below code in action [here](https://ideone.com/g5QZkY).

```
final String result = str.replaceAll("\\p{L}", "");
```

Comment: Do it as `str.replaceAll("[\\p{Alpha}]", "");` so that non-english characters can also be handled. Check [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for details.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash `Alpha` looks to me like a synonym for the ASCII English alphabet a-z & A-Z, according to your linked document. Did you mean to say `\p{IsAlphabetic}`?

Comment: @BasilBourque - After some more research I found that the most appropriate pattern for this is `[\\p{L}]`. This is also mentioned on the same page (3 places below where `\p{IsAlphabetic}` has been mentioned.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash Thank you.